# Finding the area of triangle if length of medians are given

Tags: geometry, triangles

My question is:

> In triangle ABC ,length of median from vertex A is $13$ , length of
>   median from vertex B is $14$ , length of median from vertex C is $15$.
>   Compute the area of triangle ABC.

Comment: See formula 3 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleMedian.html).

Answer (score 1):

One strategy, probably not optimal, is to find the lengths of the sides, and then use Heron's Formula.

Take a triangle $XYZ$, with sides $x$, $y$, $z$ as usual, and let $m$ be the length of the median from $Z$ to the side $XY$, which has length $z$.

Let $P$ be the midpoint of $XY$.  We have divided our triangle into two triangles, $ZPX$ and $ZPY$.  Let $\theta=\angle ZPX$ and $\phi=\angle ZPY$. Note that $\theta+\phi=\pi$.  By the Cosine Law, we have
$$y^2=m^2+\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^2-mz\cos\theta.$$
Also by the Cosine Law, we have
$$x^2=m^2+\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^2-mz\cos\phi.$$
But $\cos\phi=-\cos\theta$. Add. The awkward cosine terms cancel, and we get
$$x^2+y^2=2m^2+2\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^2,$$
which yields the result
$$m^2=\frac{1}{4}\left(2x^2+2y^2-z^2\right).$$

The rest is downhill. We go back to the triangle of the question. The three lengths of the medians give us three linear equations in the **squares** of the side lengths. If the sides of our triangle are $a$, $b$, and $c$, we get
$$4\cdot 13^2=2a^2+2b^2-c^2;\quad 4\cdot 14^2=2b^2+2c^2-a^2;\quad 4\cdot 15^2=2c^2+2a^2-b^2.$$
Solve. A simple  way is to use the symmetry of the equations by first of all "adding" the above three equations to first find $a^2+b^2+c^2$.

Now that we  have the sides, we can use Heron's Formula.

Answer (score 1):

Use formula:

$$A = \frac{4}{3} \sqrt{s \cdot (s_m - m_1) \cdot (s_m - m_2) \cdot (s_m - m_3)} $$

where $m_1$ = 1st median, $m_2$ = 2nd median, $m_3$ = 3rd median, $s_m = (m_1+m_2+m_3)/2$

It is one of simplest method

Regards
Jay Sharma

Answer (score -2):

Area: $$\Delta=\dfrac 43\sqrt {s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$
Where $a,b$ & $c$ are median lengths & $s$ is the semi-perimeter.

Comment: The formula is a little off. Correct it.