# Prove that the area of the triangle formed by the medians is equal to $3/4$ the area of the original triangle

Tags: contest-math

This is Question $2$ from [this](https://kskedlaya.org/geometryunbound/geom-080399.pdf) document on Olympiad Geometry.

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $M_A,M_B,M_C$ the midpoints of the sides $BC, CA, AB$, respectively. Show that the triangle with side lengths $AM_A, BM_B, CM_C$ has area $3/4$ that of the triangle $ABC$.

This is part of a chapter that stresses that by "slicing and dicing", we can solve a lot of complicated problems. Hence, the stress is on diagrammatic proofs.

To form a triangle with the medians, I extended $AM_A$ beyond $BC$, and formed another copy of the triangle $ABC$. My diagram looks like this:
[image]

Obviously $BP=CM_C$. Hence, if $PM_B=AM_A$, we'll have created a triangle with the medians as sides.

> So my question is, is $AM_A=PM_B$? A followup question would be is it easy to see that the area of the triangle $BPM_B$ is equal to $3/8$ that of the parallelogram given?

Comment: **Hint:** Yes, $AM_{A} = PM_{B}$. Look at triangles $\triangle CPM_B$ and $\triangle CA'A$. They are similar.

Comment: @SameerKailasa- Haha yes should've seen that. How about proving that the area of $BPM_B$ is equal to $3/8$ the area of $ABCA'$? Is it easy to see from this diagram?

Comment: You will find very inspiring the answers of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/396085

Comment: Besides, use for example geogebra to draw your figures instead of a photograph of an approximate figure drawn on a blackboard :)

Comment: See as well http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/Medians.Triangle/Area.Medians.Tri.html

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://gogeometry.blogspot.com/2016/12/geometry-problem-1296-herons-formula.html

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the question, whether $AM_A=PM_B$, the answer is YES.

Simply observe that $$\frac{CP}{CA'}=\frac{CM_B}{CA}$$ Thus, in virtue of the [Intercept theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) (also known as "Thales' Theorem") $$\frac{PM_B}{AA'}=\frac{CP}{CA'}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Can you end it now?

---

Alternatively, here you have a proof (almost) without words.
[image]

*Definition*: $[...]$ denotes the area of the polygon "..."

Observe that $CE$ is a median in $\Delta CDH$. Thus

> $$1=\frac{DK}{KH}\frac{[DKE]}{[EKH]}=\frac{[DKC]}{[KHC]}=\frac{[DKC]-[DKE]}{[KHC]-[EKH]}=\frac{[DEC]}{[EHC]}\iff [DEC]=[EHC]$$ Similarly $$[DEC]=[DHE]=[EHC]$$

Futhermore $$[DEC]=\frac{[ABC]}{4}$$ Can you end it now?

Comment: Nice presentation. A little remark : "Intercept theorem" has another very common name in many countries which is "Thales theorem"

Comment: In Spain we also know it as "Thales Theorem", but when I looked it up in the English Wikipedia, I fount "intercepting theorem"...- Edited!

Comment: Thanks for the manes of this mathematician !

Comment: +1 @Dr.Mathva  ...