# Finding the area of a triangle if the distances from the centroid to the vertices are $3$, $4$, $5$

Tags: geometry, centroid

> Let $G$ be the centroid of $\triangle ABC$, and let $AG=3$, $BG=4$, $CG=5$. Find the area of $\triangle ABC$.

So I calculated the lengths of the diagonals which is $9$, $12$, $15$, but now I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Have a look here, maybe: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396085/how-to-find-area-of-triangle-from-its-medians

Comment: Thank you this helped very much